# Erro caso o usuário não liberar GeoLocalização

Tags: javascript, html5, api

Estou colocando geolocalização em um site de um cliente, só que estou tendo um problema em fazer alguma função que chame um `alert()` caso o usuário não dê permissão para o browser usar a geolocalização. O que eu quero é só exibir um `alert()` quando o usuário negar. Meu código atual

```
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);

    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("trajeto-texto"));

}


function getPosition(){

    if ( navigator.geolocation ){

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function( posicao ){

            var positions = new Array();

            positions['latitude'] = posicao.coords.latitude;
            positions['longitude'] = posicao.coords.longitude;

            initialize();

            var enderecoPartida = '08210-791, Brasil';
            var enderecoChegada = '08215-255, Brasil';

            var request = {
                origin: enderecoPartida,
                destination: enderecoChegada,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
            });


        } );

    }
}

getPosition();
```

tentei deixar essa linha **navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function( posicao ){** dessa forma **navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function( posicao, error ){** mas não deu certo.

Comment: Opa, nao cheguei a utilizar a api do google maps, porem uma ideia aqui... voce pode setar uma funcao com  settimeout(function(){},time); e verificar se tem conteudo dentro da div mapa, caso tenha conteudo é pq carregou, correto?

Comment: sim, e como faria essa verificação ? tem algum código de exemplo ai? não sou tão bom com o JS. Pesquisei aqui e o problema parece ser no Firefox do Ubuntu, que é o que uso, mas vi gente fazendo algo com setTimeOut() só que estava em inglês e ignorei.

Answer (score 1):

`watchPosition` aceita, como segundo parâmetro, um callback caso ocorra um erro - um dos possíveis sendo a permissão negada.

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
  // Código caso o usuário tenha aceito.
},
function (error) { 
  if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
      // Caso o usuário tenha negado.
});
```

[Referência.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation)

Comment: O Problema parece ser com o Firefox do ubuntu (o que estou usando). Teria alguma tática para driblar esse erro ?

Comment: se tiver algum plugin no firefox tente desabilitar todos.